# Add an external child in React

Tags: reactjs, webpack

I need to add another react component that's located in an external CDN as a child in my react component. Something like this:

```
var RemoteComponent = require('//cdn.com/some-remote-component');
var MyComponent = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    return (
      <div>
        <RemoteComponent />
      </div>
    );
  }
});
module.exports = MyComponent;
```

Any ideas on how could I do that?

Comment: Did you try using a `<script>` tag?

Comment: It should be a local and run in nodejs

Comment: Are you against downloading it and bringing it into your app?

Comment: Actually the external component url is given dynamicaly by MyComponent props and could change through user interaction. Sorry for not being very clear on the question...

Comment: Does the remote component download must happen at run time or at build time?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the component registers to a global you could use a script loader such as [script.js](https://github.com/ded/script.js/). Note that it is an asynchronous process so that will lead to some complexity. You may need to run the component through `React.createFactory` before plugging it in dynamically.

I expect you'll need to do something like this (not tested):

```
export default MyComponent {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      component: null
    };

    $script('cdn url goes here', () => {
      // expects to find a global named `RemoteComponent` now
      this.setState({
        component: React.createFactory(RemoteComponent);
      })
    });
  }
  render() {
    const component = this.state.component;    

    return (
      <div>
        {component}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

You may need to tweak the code to your liking but I hope it illustrates the basic idea.

Comment: @theusguy Did you encounter some particular issue with the approach?

Answer (score -1):

You can also build your own function to load remote react components without using requirejs or scriptjs. It can be very straightforward as follows (I was inspired by the solution [here](https://gist.github.com/tonytonyjan/616022dce75f8e6c1603bbeb94ec46a4))

```
import React from 'react';

export function loadRemoteComponent(url) {
  return fetch(url)
    .then(response => response.text())
    .then(text => {
      // Define exports and require method for eval(text)
      const exports = {};
      function require(name) {
        if (name === 'react') {
          return React;
        }
        throw new Error('Does not support modules other than "react"');
      }
      eval(text);
      return exports.__esModule ? exports.default : exports;
    });
}
```